# xPUD doesn't recognize Wi-Fi adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, dell-inspiron

I saw [xPUD](http://www.xpud.org/), and decided to give it a try. It's basically the same concept as Chromium/Chrome OS - boot (nearly) straight into the browser, only it's Firefox-based instead of Chrome/Chromium-based.

Unfortunately, my D-Link DWA-160 Wi-Fi adapter is not recognized. What do I need to do to get connected?
UPDATE: Tried hooking it directly into the router via Ethernet, but it's not recognized. I've tried using DHCP and using a static local IP, but nothing works. `ifup eth0` returns `Can't open "/etc/network/interfaces": No such file or directory` - I'm not sure whether I need to run a Modprobe, or what.

I am mildly proficient in Linux - there's no way I could compile a kernel module or anything like that, but if you ask me to "burn" an ISO to a USB drive, or mess around with partitions, I won't be confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to http://mesrss.free.fr/xpud/opt/ and download "extra drivers".
You can chuck that onto your boot stick, and do an offline opt install from the settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).